# How can i avoid multiple ajax calls here on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, timer, callback

i have a button that says "Next" and everytime i click it, it that increments a value and generate an ajax call with a callback.

The issue is that sometimes i want to click it multiple times in a row to increment by 3 or 4 so i click on the "Next" button repeatedly.

I basically want some throttle so until kick off the ajax call if you haven't got a "Next" button click in the last 1 second or something like that.

This way, if i click on it multiple times really fast, it will only fire off the ajax call on the last value.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: some code would help, right now the only thing I can think of is to increment your value, i.e. value += 3; | value += 4; in stead of clicking the button multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var timer;
$('selector').on('click', function (){
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        // ajax call
    }, lengthofdelay);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#next_button").click(function() {
    var now = $(this).val(); $(this).val(now++); //increment value
    if (timer) { 
       clearTimeout(timer); //abort ajax call if button clicked within 1 sec, and start over
    }
    timer = setTimeout(doAjax, 1000); //do ajax call in 1 second
});


function doAjax() {
    //do ajax call here
}
```

Comment: They are defined by The Mozilla Organisation in the specifications for ECMAscript?

Comment: @leora, those are the inbuilt functions to handle the javascript timing events. You can get a clear idea about these javascript timing events at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp), hope this will help you.